# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, xampp

Hello I am new to sql and only really using it for JDBC, i am trying to create a database call SuperMarket and create the tables with this sql script

```
CREATE TABLE item (
ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_item PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30),
price DOUBLE PRECISION,
quantity INT
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_customer PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_employee PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30),
password VARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE trans (
ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_transaction PRIMARY KEY,
employee INT,
customer INT,
is_open INT
);

CREATE TABLE acquisition (
ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_acquisition PRIMARY KEY,
trans INT,
item INT,
quantity INT
);
```

When i try to import it in phpMyAdmin using xampp i get the following error:

```
Number 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT pk_item PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30),
price DOUBLE PRECISION,
qua' at line 2
```

I still cannot find any syntax error can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
   ID INT NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(30),
   price DOUBLE PRECISION,
   quantity INT,

   CONSTRAINT pk_item PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Your `CONSTRAINT` keyword was in the wrong spot.  Same goes for the rest of the tables as well.

If you simply want ID to be the primary key, you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(30),
   price DOUBLE PRECISION,
   quantity INT
);
```